# How to show "go to controller" in page view (cshtml) in VS 2022?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2022

I'm using the MVC pattern for web development. After updating to the 2022 version, I can no longer find the "go to controller" tool in the context menu in the page views (.cshtml).

Can anyone tell me where it is please?

Answer (score 4):

Sure is a hassle. I've got the same. Shortcut still works though:

Ctrl-M + Ctrl-G